# Cartoon show about a man who went to a restaurant/restroom not knowing it was a government testing facility

Tags: story-identification, aliens, cartoon, planets

I am looking a cartoon I found in YouTube. It is sort of like an animation mix video about a modern normal Earth guy who went to a restaurant or restroom without realising it is a government testing facility and he was shot in space and landed on alien planet and he kinda lives there. I'm not sure he came back to earth. The premise is basically fish out of water like Futurama except he just lives on a different planet and not the future.

Comment: https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/AccidentalAstronaut

Comment: Yeah like that except I'm not sure he come back to earth and promise is basically fish out of water like futurama except he just lives on a different planet and not the future